# Is it possible to connect multiple DHT11 modules to Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: pi-2, sensor

Can I read at least 3 `DHT11` sensors using `GPIO` with a Raspberry Pi 3?

And if yes, how?

Now I only have 1 DHT11 connected to the Raspberry Pi, but I used a library and I don't know how to add more sensors...

Comment: Yes, it certainly is. Please review [help](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @stevieb sorry the question was bad formuled

Comment: I added a help link to my comment. Please read through that, and the other documentation it links to.

Comment: Your new updates do not help things. I really don't mean to be indignant, but you need to help yourself before you can get help here. I recommend you break the problem apart... you've added a DHT11 hygrometer to your Pi; does it work? What library? What pins? If yes it does work, how are you adding another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More detail would enable a better and more specific answer, but in generalities:

- Yes, you can add more DHT-11 modules. You can probably keep adding them until you run out of GPIO pins.
- Each module will need its own pin (I think).
- The library will almost certainly have some means of specifying the pin used by the module. For example using the Adafruit DHT-11/22 library you would make a call like this to construct a DHT-11 object:

  `dht  = adafruit_dht.DHT22(board.D2)`

  Where `board.D2` tells the library where the board is connected. To add an additional module you'd call the constructor again.

Take some time to read through the documentation for the module and your library. Then if you still need help tell us what you've tried and post the code that you're working on (or a relevant snippet).

Comment: Thank You Very much!

Yeea, it has a syntax: `dht = adafruit_dht(DHT_MODEL, DHT_PIN)`